# Determine fragment before current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Imagine there is fragment A and fragment B.
if I click the button on fragment A, it leads to fragment C.
if I click the button on fragment B, it also leads to fragment C.
Now I want to detect from which fragment does the fragment C is created. Is it possible?

Comment: where do you want to check that in fragment C??

Comment: check in one of the function in fragment C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set a variable and pass that to Fragment C through bundle while doing FragmentTransaction like this as shown

```
Fragment fr=new FragmentA();
FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("from", "fragmentA");
fr.setArguments(args);
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
ft.commit();
```

and you can retrieve the same in Fragment C like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("from"); // with value of strtext,you will get to know from which fragment you come from   
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: is there any way to detect it using back stack or something like that? because there may be a lot of other fragment that leads to fragment C

Comment: so what you have to just copy paste this code everytime when you make transaction to Fragment C and the code in Fragment C remains same all the time. If you don't want to go this way,you can set a variable in your preferences and then use that to distinguish between different fragments in Fragment C

Answer (score 1):

```
##You can pass a boolean value and toggle between two fragments.##
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putBoolean("key",true) // for fragement A
fr.setArguments(args);
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
ft.commit(); 
if(getArguments().getBoolean("key");)
Log.e(LOGTAG,"FROM FRAGMENT A");
else
Log.e(LOGTAG,"FROM FRAGMENT B");
```